# Confusion over sign convention for power

Tags: circuit-analysis

We are given this electrical circuit:

[image]

At the last line, they put a 'minus'.

My question is, why is it a minus?

Comment: Consumer consensus?

Comment: @MattYoung That was a free translation from my native language. I meant Passive sign convention!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Because whoever drew the circuit is adhering to the [passive sign convention](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Passive_sign_convention), which states that active devices that *source* power have a negative power term, and passive devices that *sink* power have a positive power term.

Resistance is always positive, any real quantity squared is positive, and therefore \$RI_S^2\$ must be a positive quantity. Consequently, \$-12\cdot RI_S^2\$ must be a negative quantity; the negative is added to adhere to the convention.